# Why is CodeContract warning about a null reference, when the ObjectInvariant checks it for null

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Am trying to get up to speed with Code Contracts.  Here is another issue that doesn't make sense to me:

This is the Invariant:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
    void Invariant() {
        Contract.Invariant(this._uiRoot.RowDefinitions!=null);
    }
```

Then, in a Method is this code:

```
int colunmn = 0;
foreach (UIElement uiElement in row.Where(element => element!=null))
{
            if (uiElement != null)
            {
                uiElement.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, colunmn++);
                uiElement.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, _uiRoot.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
                _uiRoot.Children.Add(uiElement);
            }
}
```

I then get a warning that _uiRoot.RowDefinitions may be null, despite the Invariant.  I don't see why CodeContracts would think that if it is checked after every public method call and the constructor.  The code in question is a custom form designer, and it uses the uiRoot.RowDefinitions in a number of different methods, which is why I wanted to put it into the Invariant.  I thought this would be enough to stop the warnings on it.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe make a separate Invariant for `_uiRoot != null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think invariant only runs on public property access.  Is it possible to add a contract to the RowDefinitions property itself?  Your invariant can't prove that property won't be null; you could call a method on that type which sets it to null after your invariant runs.